# How to get multiplication of two column's value which is nearly equal (highest decimal) in the third column using SQL/Python?

Tags: python, sql, excel, loops, multiplication

I have a dataset named df

[image]

Multiplicating two columns (Open and low, which have the **equal values**) should give the result nearly equal to the **highest** integer (decimal) value referring to the 'High' column & store the result in High_new with its corresponding date.

For example in the table attached -

Open and High both columns have equal value (100) so 100*2 = 200 and 200.8 is the highest decimal(integer) value which is closest to 200, so we get 200.8 in High_new column and its corresponding date (refer output dataset) (** Note - we haven't considered 200.3 since 200.8 is highest decimal value of 200)

So, how do I get column High_new and date_new column? (Can be solved using python/SQL)

I have tried below code so far (sharing the output of this too)

** (This is just the initial logic which might work) -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = {'Date':['11/1/18', '12/3/18', '1/1/19', '2/1/19', '3/1/19'],
        'Open':[72, 99, 101.25, 92.05, 100],
        'High':[115.4, 144.3, 200.8, 200.3, 135.5],
        'Low' :[72,91,88.3,84,100]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df

df['high2'] = np.where(df['Open'] == df['Low'], df['Open']*2, np.nan)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code so we have something to work with.

Comment: @Mr.Jones I have tried this on sample data. But then the same question exists as to how I can achieve the desired output

Comment: Why does 100/100 produce 200.8 when 92.05/84 produces 200.3?  That makes no sense at all.  Shouldn't it be "the smallest value greater than open+low"?

Comment: @TimRoberts we aren't getting the 'High_new' with some multiplication or division. If Open = Low, then we should do Open *2 (like 100 *2 = 200) and then look for the nearest highest decimal number close to 200 from column 'High' and that value will go in 'high2'.

Comment: Yes, but the closest number to 100*2 is 200.3, not 200.8.

Comment: @TimRoberts But I need 200.8 as a result of query (highest decimal of 200). If we had 200.9 in this case, then we would have picked 200.9 and not 200.8.

Comment: Why?  Why doesn't line 3 do that?  It sums to 189.55.  What is the "rule"?  You can't teach it to a computer unless there is a "rule".

Comment: @TimRoberts There's rule over here (first of all we are NOT summing any column to get High_new column). RULE 1 -> If Open = Low, then Open *2 and select a value from 'High' column which have the highest decimal integer of it (like in the last case, we have 100=100 (open = low) so, 100*2 = 200 hence we pick 200.8 from 'High' column. RULE 2 -> If Open != Low, then High = 'High_new' (for example row 2 of output table).

Comment: @TimRoberts, thanks so much for the answer. It's as I was expecting !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the "largest decimal" thing to be unusual and likely to be a misunderstanding, but this does what you ask.  I create a separate dataframe to keep the largest fraction within each integer, and then do a row-by-row to look up the closest.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date':['11/1/18', '12/3/18', '1/1/19', '2/1/19', '3/1/19'],
        'Open':[72, 99, 101.25, 92.05, 100],
        'High':[115.4, 144.3, 200.8, 200.3, 135.5],
        'Low' :[72,91,88.3,84,100]}
  
# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a dataframe with only the highest for each integer.

sub = df[['Date','High']].sort_values(by='High')
sub['IntHigh'] = df['High'].astype(int)
sub.drop_duplicates('IntHigh',keep='last', inplace=True)

# Find closest high for each row where open==low.

def findclosest(row):
    if row['Open'] != row['Low']:
        return row['High'],row['Date']

    sub['Delta'] = (sub['IntHigh']-row['Open']*2).abs()
    chk = sub.sort_values('Delta').index[0]
    return sub.loc[chk,['High','Date']]

df[['High2','Date2']] = df.apply( findclosest, axis=1 )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Date    Open   High    Low  High2    Date2
0  11/1/18   72.00  115.4   72.0  144.3  12/3/18
1  12/3/18   99.00  144.3   91.0  144.3  12/3/18
2   1/1/19  101.25  200.8   88.3  200.8   1/1/19
3   2/1/19   92.05  200.3   84.0  200.3   2/1/19
4   3/1/19  100.00  135.5  100.0  200.8   1/1/19
```